# Decoding the output buffer from MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm using the Android MediaCodec library to decode a video stored on the file system. I get an  output buffer that looks legit (with proper `bufferinfo.offset` and `size`). Its format seems to be 256 (which is JPEG). I tried decoding it with `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`, but the result was `null`.

Does anyone know the correct way to ascertain the format of the output buffer? What's the correct way to start decoding the output byte arrays?

Answer (score 2):

The `MediaCodec` color formats are defined by the [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html) class.  256 is used internally, and generally doesn't mean that you have a buffer of JPEG data.  The confusion here is likely because you're looking at constants in the `ImageFormat` class, but those only apply to camera output.  (For example, `ImageFormat.NV16` is a YCbCr format, while `COLOR_Format32bitARGB8888` is RGB, but both have the numeric value 16.)

Some examples of `MediaCodec` usage, including links to CTS tests that exercise `MediaCodec`, can be found [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).  On some devices you will not be able to decode data from the `ByteBuffer` output, and must instead decode to a `Surface`.

Comment: I actually figured this out a little bit. MediaCodec has an "event" called "output format changed". Here, you get access to a new MediaFormat object that should have the color format of the output buffer. In my case, it wasn't 256 (JPEG data). It was something from the MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities class - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar

Comment: Yup.  If you look at `EncodeDecodeTest.java` on the page I linked, it gets the format at line 619, and passes it to `checkFrame()`.  At line 966 the color format is compared against the known formats to decide how to proceed.